# Is it a good practice the attach an event related parameter to an object's model as a variable?

Tags: api, oop

This is about an API handling the validation during saving an object. Which means that the front-end client sends a request to the API to a specific end point, then on the back-end the API creates a new object if the right conditions are meet.

Right now the regular method that we use is that the models has a ruleset for each fields and then the validation is invoked when the save function is invoked, but technically the validation is done right before the object is saved into the database.

Then during today's code review I came across a solution which I wasn't sure if it's a good practice or not. And it was about that the front-end must send a specific parameter to the API every time. This is because other APIs are using our API as well, and we needed to know if the request was sent as and API request or a browser request. If this parameter is present then we want to execute an extra validation function on a specific field.

(1)If I would have to implement it, then I would check the incoming parameter in the service handler or in the controller level, and if I got one, I would invoke the validation right away, and if it fails I would throw an error.

(2)The implementation I saw however adds an extra variable to the model, and sets the model variable when there is an incoming parameter, then validates only when the save function is invoked on the object(which first validates the ruleset defined on the object fields, then saves the object into the database)

So my problem with (2) is that the object now grown bigger with an extra variable that is only related to a specific event. So I would say it's better to implement (1). But (2) also has an advantage, and that is when you create the object on different end point by parsing the parameters, then the validation will work there as well, even if the developer forget to update the code there.

Now this may seems like a silly question because, why would I care about just 1 extra variable, but this is like a bedrock of something good or bad. So if I say this is ok, then from now on the models will start growing with extra variables that are only related to specific events, which I think should be handled on the controller/service handler level. On the other hand the code would be more reliable if it's not the developer who should remember all the 6712537 functionalities and keep them in mind when makes some changes somewhere. Let's say all the devs will get heart attack tomorrow from the excitement of an amazing discovery, and a new developer has to work on the project while he doesn't know about these small details, and then he has to change something on the code that is related to this functionality - so that new feature should be supported by this old one as well.

So my question is if is there any good practice on this, and what do you think what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

So I spent some time on thinking on the solution, and I think the best is to have an array of acceptable trigger variables in the model class. Then when the parameters are passed to the model on the controller level, then the loader function can be modified that it takes the trigger variables from the parameters and save it in the model's associative array variable that stores the trigger variables.

By default this array is empty, and it doesn't matter how much new variables are needed to be created, it will only contain the necessary ones when those are used.

Then of course the loader function needs to be modified in a way that it can filter out the non trigger variables as well as it is done for the regular fields, and there can be even a rule set of validation on the trigger variables if necessary.

So this solves the problem with overgrowing the object with unnecessary variables and the centralized validation part, because now the validation can be always done in the model instead of the controller.
And since the loader function is modified to store the trigger variables in the model's trigger variables array variable, the developer never has to remember that this functionality was created. Which is good, because in the future when he creates a new related function or end point that should handle object creation, he will not miss it to validate it against the old functionality, because the the loader function that he modified in the past like this will handle it for him.

It needs to be noted tho, that since the loader function doesn't differentiate between the parameters, and where to load them other then checking the names of the parameters with the filter functions, these parameter names should be identical from each other, otherwise a buggy functionality can be created accidentally. Like if you forget that a model attribute with the same name was used, then you can accidentally trigger an event that was programmed to be triggered if the trigger variable with the same name is present. However this can be solved by prefixing the trigger variables for example.